# VHDL generate a constant signal

Tags: vhdl

I need to generate a constant high signal pulse_out to output to an oscilloscope.

I tried letting the output signal pulse_out <='1' and this didnt work either.   I believe due to my knowledge that an output port signal needs to be driven by a clock.

I also tried using combinational logic and letting a two signals that were opposite of each other make a new signal by using AND,OR and this did not work either.

I know it is a stupid question, but I am stumped.
Any sample code of showing how to output a constant high value of '1' would be great.

Comment: Are you sure that your constraint file, which maps your ports by name to IO pins is correct? This is the first place I would look.

Comment: I figured it out it was my .ucf file.  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Josh's comment on checking your pin numbers and pin report to make sure you are driving the pin you think you are. Setting a signal to '1' should drive the pin high.

You can double check it too by driving a divided clock out and give yourself an edge to trigger a scope on.

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;
USE ieee.std_logic_arith.ALL;

ENTITY test IS
 PORT (i_clk   : IN  std_logic;
       i_reset : IN  std_logic;
       o_scope : OUT std_logic
       );
END test;

ARCHITECTURE behv OF test IS

SIGNAL scope : std_logic;

BEGIN
p1 : PROCESS (i_clk, i_reset)
 BEGIN
  IF i_reset = RESET_LEVEL THEN
   scope <= '0';
  ELSIF clk'event AND clk = '1' THEN
   scope <= NOT scope;
  END IF;
 END PROCESS p1;
 o_scope <= scope;
END behv;
```